# How to call postgre native function wih pg-promise Columnset

Tags: pg-promise

I need to encrypt data and insert into table.
I am using pg-promise, pgp.helper to create columset and then calling pgp.helper.insert.
If I try to insert data without encrypting it, it is working fine but I want to use postgres native function "pgp_sym_encrypt" to encrypt data while inserting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per type [Column](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.Column.html), your column definition can be like this:

```
{
    name: 'your-column-name',
    mod: ':raw',
    init: c => pgp.as.format('PGP_SYM_ENCRYPT($1, $2)', [c.value, 'AES_KEY'])
}
```